# Telegram не парсит HTML

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Всем бобра!
Пишу бота на Google Apps Script, хочу научить его отправлять форматированный в HTML текст (параметр text метода sendMessage), но парсинг по какой-то причине не работает, бот не отправляет сообщение.

```js
function sendMessage(chat_id, text, parse_mode) {
let url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text="+ text + '&parse_mode=' + parse_mode;
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response.getContentText()); 
}

function doPost(e) {
let update = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
let msg = update.message;
let chatId = msg.chat.id;
let text = msg.text;
let welcomeText = '<b>Hey!</b>';

//проверяем является ли update сообщением
if (update.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
  // проверяем является ли сообщение оповещением о новом члене группы
  if (msg.hasOwnProperty('new_chat_participant')){
    sendMessage(chatId, welcomeText, 'HTML');
  }
}
```

Если HTML-теги не использовать, то сообщения отправляются. Также, если заменить [HTML](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) на [MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style), то при применении соответствующей разметки форматирование работает, но с Markdown работать неудобно:(. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: HTML-сущности тоже не парсятся:(

Comment: что значит не парсятся? мы не будем с бубном и плясками играть в угадайки, поэтому никто не захочет помогать.

Comment: При использовании HTML-тегов бот не присылает сообщения вовсе. При использовании HTML-сущностей бот присылает только неформатированный текст, который расположен перед первой HTML-сущностью.

Comment: Возможно, надо сделать `encodeURIComponent`, попробуйте `"&text="+ encodeURIComponent(text)`.  А что за метод `fetch`, откуда он?

Comment: Работает! Спасибо огромное! fetch это метод GAS https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app